# Angular 11 HTTPClient will not encode "/" in query params

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, urlencode, angular11

So for some reason unknown to me, angular seems to have no way of encoding the / to %2F.

I've tried const encoder = new HttpUrlEncodingCodec. And encoding the value.
I've also tried javascripts encodeURIComponent, which does work when logging the value, but in the network tab it is double encoded to %252F.

I can't find anything online about how to do this, or why it isn't working on it's own.

Any support would be appreciated.

```
public requestJourneyData$(payload): Observable<any> {
 const { country, selectedGoals, endPoint } = payload;
 const encoder = new HttpUrlEncodingCodec();
 encoder.encodeKey(selectedGoals); // Does nothing
 encoder.encodeValue(selectedGoals); // Does nothing
 new HttpUrlEncodingCodec().encodeValue(selectedGoals); // does nothing
 encodeURIComponent(selectedGoals); // Does work, but not when viewed in network requests in chrome dev tools.

 return this.http.get(`${endPoint}?`, {
   params: { selectedGoals, country },
 });}
```

[image: When using encodeURIComponent]

[image]

Comment: Why do you need this? `/` doesn't have a special meaning in the query string, so there's no need to escape this.

Comment: I'm not really sure from a front end perspective. The backend piece of shi, I mean the backend engineer said that they can't accept /. But the slash is a part of the goal being selected by the user. He said they need it as %2F.

Comment: Then consider just doing a string replace. A good backend shouldn't care, and normal url-encoding functions would not encode characters that need it.

Comment: For some reason when I manually put in %2F, when I look at the network tab it still double encodes it. Is there any way of overiding angulars encoding pattern?

Comment: Yes, don't use params but just manually construct the URL (including everything after `?`)

Comment: Thank you for that. Would you be able to explain the reason this isn't working via params in angular just for my own learning, as I am unfamiliar with this area.

Comment: Likely because it expects raw values, and angular automatically encodes things for you. It's not typical to have control over this kind of thing if you let libraries do serialization for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above, it appears Angular will not allow you do manual encoding. The HttpClient does it all for you. The only current way to bypass this issue ref @evert: don't use params but just manually construct the URL (including everything after ?).

Thanks Evert!

Answer (score 0):

If your url parameters origin from an input field, you may

1. mask them, or
2. manually remove them

Masking:

Use ngx-mask package.

```js
    public customPatterns = { M: { pattern: new RegExp("[^\/]")}};
```

```html
    <input
        mask="M*"
        [patterns]="customPatterns"
        [dropSpecialCharacters]="false"
        type="text"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem recently except that when I manually encode the '=' symbol to `%D3` using `encodeURIcomponent()` the request URL shows `%25D3` indicating double encoding.

What fixed it like what others have said is to manually construct your request URL as a string and pass it that way which is a huge pain but oh well.